# Variable assignment in python: The assignment x=23 yields error when running x./4

Tags: python, variable-assignment

When I run the following program in python 2.7.5 I get

```
>>> x=23
>>> print x
23
```

Ok fine.

Similarly, type(x) is int.

When I run the following program:

```
>>> print 23./4
5.75
```

Still fine. But then when I run this final program:

```
>>> x=23
>>> print x./23
>>> File "<stdin>", line 1
print x./4
        ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i.e. I get a syntax error. But I can do other arithmetical operations with x treating it as though it were the integer 23; x+1 yields 24, x/23 yields 1 and so on. So what is going on here? p.s. this is my first post hopefully the formatting is ok.

Comment: But `x.` is not `23.`. That `.` is just invalid syntax. Variables are not macros. Nothing magical is going on here, `variable.` is just invalid syntax.

Comment: Andrew is correct in that it is an invalid syntax. What you're trying to do already has an elegant solution called casting, where you take a variable of one type and change it into another (eg. integer ==> float). Simply call float on your variable, like so: `float(x)`

Comment: `23.` is shorthand for `23.0`. Just like `x.0` doesn't make sense, neither does `x.`

Comment: There's no problem at all with `x.`. That's how you access attributes. The problem occurs when you follow that with something like `/` or a number, which aren't valid identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the following program also fails:

```
x = 10
print x5
```

even though this program works:

```
print 105
```

If the above makes sense, then the only missing part here is understanding that `23.` is a short for `23.0`, it's a single entity, not two separate (`23` and `.`).

If however my above example also seems not intuitive to you, then your understanding of variables is a little off, and I would recommend revisiting the chapter on variables in whichever textbook you are using.

Comment: What you write does make sense. Is the following roughly on the right track? :  So a variable is not just another name for the thing to which it is assigned. But if we use it in certain syntactically correct ways, (like x+3, with x=23) then it will "access" its value.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point can be part of a numeric literal.  You can't use it (as a decimal point) after a variable; in that context it would be interpreted as attribute access and would need an attribute name after it.  For the same reason, you can do `23/4`, but you can't set `x=2` and then do `x3/4`.  Using a variable does not mean its literal value is textually pasted into the code at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have been mistakenly thinking x=23 to mean that henceforth x is just another name for 23.

Comment: @qwert4321: In some sense it is, but it is a name for the *value*, not the textual representation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, to achieve that result, you have to change one of the type of one of the part of the division into float and you don't need the `.` sign. Here is what your code should be:

```
x = 23
print x / float(4)
```

Or you can make it like this

```
x = 23
print float(x) / 4
```

It will give you your desired result which is `5.75`

Hope it helps